# The many Utopias

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy

I am looking for philosophical texts that tackle the subject of Utopia.

This is what I was able to find, that wasn't a novel.

- The Republic (ca. 380 BC) by Plato - one of the earliest conceptions of a utopia.
- Sacred History (4th century BC) by Euhemerus
- Tao Hua Yuan (The Peach Blossom Spring) (421 AD) by Tao Yuanming
- Utopia (1516) by Thomas More.
- New Atlantis (1627) by Sir Francis Bacon

So are there anymore?

Also feel free to drop titles of awesome utopian/dystopian novels, at least the ones that weren't mandated reading for half the world, in the comments or something.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a list of literary work. Lists are problematic in general, and the selection isn't of philosophical nature either.

Comment: The selection I'm asking for is totally of a philosophical nature. Granted the format most utopian works are in is of a literary novel, such as 1984 by George Orwell. There are also utopias that are strictly philosophical, such as Plato's Republic. I do get that the question that wants a list as an answer is somewhat problematic for this format thing though.

Comment: For one thing, you'd have to define utopia. But even still, just because something is "philosophical" does not mean it's a good fit as a question for philosophy.se. Questions here need to be answerable in a non-list fashion.

Comment: Rather than building up a list you'd be better of asking a philosophy of politics question with reference to one of the texts; the genre of utopia , and I include dystopia in this genre as well as its an inversion of the originary text - Platos Republic, I think came out of Thomas Mores rewriting of the Republic via Aquinas City of God in terms of Christian theology; what sparks your interest in this genre?

Answer (score 3):

- News From Nowhere by William Morris; written as a novel and its content is post-revolution age. I strongly recommend it.
- Ecotopia: The Notebooks and Reports of William Weston by Ernest Callenbach

Here the some futuristic dystopian novels (according to their age of course) :

- 1984 by George Orwell
- We by Yevgeni Zamyatin
- Hunger Games by Suzanne Collins is a popular and famous not only movie bu actually a novel; may not be a full dystopia, but its dystopic.
- Jennifer Government by Max Barry; its also dystopic.

And list goes on. All these books contain the same thing: a different living styles of civilization, a different  form of government, society etc. a whole different point of view.